# Help with echoing the contents of a file that includes variables

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have the file `foo` which includes `foo ${bar}` and I have the bash script `bar`

```
bar="foo"
file=$(cat foo)
echo "$file"
```

which produces `foo ${bar}`. However I want it to produce `foo foo`.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is possible to integrate the file into the script (or to add some code to the file) then this can be accomplished with a here document:

```
foo=bar

cat <<EOT
abc
_${foo}_
def
EOT
    abc
    _bar_
    def
```

Something similar can be done with the plain file:

```
export foo=bar

commands="cat <<EOT
$(<input)
EOT"

bash -c "$commands"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind exporting the variable to your environment, then you can use `envsubst`:

```
NAME
       envsubst - substitutes environment variables in shell format strings

SYNOPSIS
       envsubst [OPTION] [SHELL-FORMAT]

DESCRIPTION
       Substitutes the values of environment variables.
```

Ex. given

```
$ cat foo
foo ${bar}
```

then

```
$ export bar="foo"
$ envsubst < foo
foo foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that using `eval`:

```
$ cat foo
foo ${bar}

$ cat bar
bar="foo"
file="$(cat foo)"
eval echo "${file}"

$ bash bar
foo foo
```

Bear in mind that `eval` could be easily abused. Please read [Eval command and security issues](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).